# What does it mean when a variable consistently has high significance in smaller lag but low significance with bigger lag in Granger causality test?

Tags: interpretation, granger-causality

I am testing the Granger causality from a number of variables to a number of stock index return (daily variable). I found that one of the variables (calling it Variable A) always have high significance when lag of 4 is included; there is also reverse causality from the return variable to the Variable A. However, Variable A has lower significance when a lag of 8 is included (still better than 10% significance) and the aforementioned reverse causality is gone.

How should I interpret the result? Some sources state that the result of Granger causality should not be dependent on the lag included. So does the behavior of aforementioned result means that I should just ignore such result?

Answer (score 0):

Granger causality uses some underlying model to decide whether there is causality or reverse causality. Like any model, having too few lags can lead to autocorrelation/serial correlation and results may not be reliable. Having too many lags can cause spurious results because you might encounter some random association between the variables.

I would suggest that you use AIC or SIC to determine the appropriate lag length for your underlying model. This means that estimate the model with different lag-lengths and choose the one that minimizes the AIC or SIC. Use that model and lag-length for your Granger Causality Test and its interpretation.

Comment: Including too many lags when testing for Granger causality is dangerous not because of spurious relationships but because of decreased power.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as the number of lag increases, my AIC decreases, but my SIC increases. So how should I choose?

Comment: You have to choose one, either AIC or SIC, and go with that. The decision may depend on your data, your objectives or the overall results that you get from each. SIC imposes a harsher penalty than AIC when you include more variables or lags. I usually prefer SIC, but ensure that there is no autocorrelation due to fewer lags.